# remove Objects from a List base on another list

Tags: java

I want to remove a List of elements Objects from list base on whatever is inside list2.
I used removeAll().
Why does the list not remove those elements that are found in list2?

Element.java

```
public class Element {

    private String element;

    public Element() {

    }

    public Element(String element) {
        setE(element);
    }


    public String getElement() {
        return element; 
    }

    public void setElement(String element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
}
```

RemoveAllTest.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class RemoveAllTest {
    public RemoveAllTest() {
        List<Element> list = new ArrayList<Element>();
        List<Element> list2 = new ArrayList<Element>();

        list.add(new Element("a"));
        list.add(new Element("b"));
        list.add(new Element("c"));

        list2.add(new Element("a"));
        list2.add(new Element("b"));
        list.removeAll(list2);

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getElement());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RemoveAllTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Element class does not implement equals. Because of they use the Object.equals() method which only tests if it is the exact same object. (i.e. that it is == ).

If you implement equals it is good practice to also implement hashCode so that equal objects will hash into the same bucket in hash data structures like Map.

Here is your Element which will not have this problem:

```
public class Element {

    private String element;

    public Element() {

    }

    public Element(String element) {
        setE(element);
    }


    public String getElement() {
        return element; 
    }

    public void setElement(String element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Element) {
            Element otherElement = (Element) other;
            if (null == element) {
                return otherElement.element == null;
            }
            return element.equals(otherElement.element);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        if (null == element) {
            return -7;
        }
        return element.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Note that we have to be careful about cases where element is null because you are not ensuring that element has a sane value. A "better" element class could avoid this if appropriate by only providing a constructor which takes a String and throwing an IllegalArgumentException if the string passed into the constructor is null, or if the setElement call takes a null value. Like so:

```
public class Element {

    private String element;

    public Element(String element) {
        setElement(element);
    }

    public String getElement() {
        return element; 
    }

    public void setElement(String element) {
        if (null == element) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element must not be null.");
        }
        this.element = element;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Element) {
            Element otherElement = (Element) other;
            return element.equals(otherElement.element);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return element.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Finally, note that null == element is better to write than element == null since you can easily forget an equal sign and end up assigning null to element. If you write null = element the compiler will complain and alert you of the dropped character.

Answer (score 4):

You need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in `Element` class.

In this case you must override `equals()` method. But as a good practice override `hashCode()` too.

Now let's try to solve your issue. You can use following as `equals()` and `hashCode()`

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Element)) return false;

    Element element1 = (Element) o;

    if (element != null ? !element.equals(element1.element) 
                                     : element1.element != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return element != null ? element.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

For more information [Why do We need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Comment: Oh no. How do I override the methods? sorry I am still learning java

Comment: For this case you do not need to override hashCode() but it is recommended to override hashCode if you are overriding equals(). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @user3871678 If  you are using IDE to coding just generate equals() and hashCode()

Comment: @Smith_61 I believe that the only reason to override hashCode is in case you intend to use these objects as keys in a Map.

Comment: @alfasin that is the main reason why they recommend it. It is meant that Objects that are equal according to equals() they must also have the same hashcode. The default implementation of Object.hashCode() does not guarantee that. Most implementations use the memory location of the Object as it's hashCode(), but we aren't supposed to know that.

Answer (score 2):

Because these are not the same elements! every time you're using `new` operator you're creating a new element!

In order to make two elements that have the same element string equals - you have to override (implement) `equals()` for example:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if (!( other instanceof Element)) {
        return false;
    }
    Element o = (Element)other;
    if (this.element == null) {
        return o.getElement() == null;
    }
    return this.element.equals(o.getElement());
}
```

Comment: Downvoting without a comment is lame!

Comment: No idea who added the downvote, but I upvoted because your answer contains the correct information that was needlessly downvoted.

Comment: This is not properly guarding the NPE. If element is null but o.element is not null the second clause of the or statement will throw an NPE.

Comment: @alfasin sorry but you are incorrect. you are using || not &&. false || true evaluates to true. If element == null and o.element != null then the first condition evaluates to false and we evaluate the second condition at which point this.element throws an NPE. If it were false && true I would agree that Java will short circuit the evaluation and avoid the second clause. If the first condition evaluates to true the second evaluation will be skipped with ||. If the first condition is false the second condition will be skipped with &&. Otherwise the second condition must be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Use following Element class it should help you.

```
class Element {

private String element;

public Element() {

}

public Element(String element) {
    setElement(element);
}


public String getElement() {
    return element; 
}

public void setElement(String element) {
    this.element = element;
}

public boolean equals(Object object)
{
    Element now=(Element)object;
    if (object == null || object.getClass() != getClass()) 
    {
        result = false;
    }
    else if(this.getElement().equals(now.getElement()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public int hashCode() 
 {
    if(element!=null)
      return element.hashCode();
    else
      return 0;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, as an alternative to the other answers, simply reuse the same objects in both lists:

```
Element a = new Element("a");
Element b = new Element("b");
Element c = new Element("c");

list.add(a);
list.add(b);
list.add(c);

list2.add(a);
list2.add(b);
list.removeAll(list2);

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getElement());
}
```

output:

> c